# IntelliJ IDETalk on Linux

Tags: intellij-idea, redhat

I have used IDETalk on a Windows and it discovers other users in my Local network working under same project. Works magic.
However on a linux machine I am not seeing any users. there are other users in my network that are using linux and have the IDETalk enabled. Does this plugin work only on Windows? Shouldn't be thugh.
Also The tool buttons like add users do not work for me. Installed is IDEtalk 0.5.6.2 and I am on redhat 6